# Question about the union in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Consider $A$ and $B$ subobjects of $C$ in an abelian category, and $\iota_A : A \rightarrow C$ and $\iota_B : B \rightarrow C$ the inclusions as subobjects.

On the one hand we have $a : A\rightarrow A\cup B$ and $b : B\rightarrow A\cup B$ the inclusion monomorphisms from the definition of union as the join of subobjects.

Using matrix notation we may have $(a\ b) : A\oplus B \rightarrow A\cup B$ and $(\iota_A\ \iota_B) : A\oplus B \rightarrow C$.

On the other hand we have the union as the epi-mono factorization of $(\iota_A\ \iota_B)$ as
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A\oplus B @>{coim\ (\iota_A\ \iota_B)}>> A\cup B @>{im\ (\iota_A\ \iota_B)}>> C
\end{CD}

Is it the case that $coim\ (\iota_A\ \iota_B) = (a\ b)$ ?

Comment: Take $C = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $A = \langle (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\rangle$, $B = \langle (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\rangle$. How is $A \oplus B$ a subobject of $C$ ?

Comment: @Kovomaka oops, excuse me, I wrote down the definition incorrectly. Thanks for the clarification. (Edited.)

Comment: Ok ! Now yes, $\mathrm{coim} (\iota_A\ \iota_B) = (a\ b)$ since $(a\ b)$, which is an epimorphism, followed by $A \cup B \hookrightarrow C$, is clearly an epi-mono factorization of $(\iota_A\ \iota_B)$.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about that exactly but still I can't prove (a b) is epi. Seems it should be obvious to be honest. (Was thinking about considering the kernel of the map from the definition of epi but didn't get anywhere.) Also, you may write this down as an answer so I can accept it if you care about that. Cheers!
@Kovomaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that *the* epi-mono factorization is only unique up to isomorphism, so the best we can do is show that $(a\ b) : A \oplus B \to A \cup B$ followed by the inclusion $A \cup B \hookrightarrow C$ is *an* epi-mono factorization of $(\iota_A\ \iota_B)$.

Consider the following diagram :

[image: Commutative diagram with A, B, their direct sum and join]

We defined $(\iota_A\ \iota_B)$ to be the factorization of the cocone given by $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$, but $a$ and $b$ each followed by the inclusion $A \cup B \hookrightarrow C$ give the same cocone, hence $(\iota_A\ \iota_B)$ indeed factors through $(a\ b)$ :
$$(\iota_A\ \iota_B) : A \oplus B \xrightarrow{(a\ b)} A \cup B \hookrightarrow C$$
The second morphism is clearly a monomorphism, hence it remains to show that $(a\ b)$ is epic.

Since we are working in a (small) abelian category $\mathbf{C}$, we can use the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem : $\mathbf{C}$ is equivalent to some full subcategory of some module category $R-\mathrm{Mod}$. In such a category of modules over a ring, $A \oplus B \to A \cup B$ is given by $(a, b) \mapsto a+b$ (as $A \cup B$ is none other than $A + B$), which is surjective, thus an epimorphism. Now epimorphisms in $R-\mathrm{Mod}$ are epimorphisms in the subcategory $\mathbf{C}$, so $(a\ b)$ is indeed epic in $\mathbf{C}$.

Maybe (I hope) there is a nicer argument that doesn't use Freyd-Mitchell.

Comment: Ok, so I just saw this again after a few days and it was pretty simple. (a b) is the unique morphism from A⊕B to AUB that makes some triangles commute. But by the definition of the union, it must be an epi-mono factorization with an epi up to the union and a mono from the union to the union (the id in this case). Therefore (a  b) is epic.
As a note, I must imagine Freyd-Mitchell ends up being circular somehow. I can't imagine this is never used in any proposition leading to it.
Anyway, thanks again for the messages. Cheers!